# UIManagedDocument: How to perform saving in background

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uimanageddocument

I have a Table View hooked up to a NSFetchedResultsController, and the corresponding managedObjectContext is self.myDatabase.managedObjectContext:

```
self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                    managedObjectContext:self.myDatabase.managedObjectContext
                                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                               cacheName:nil];
```

Now, whenever the user refreshes the page I execute the following code. In essence, I create a new thread to load the data and then update/save the new data on the MOC-safe thread:

```
dispatch_queue_t fetchQ = dispatch_queue_create("fetcher", NULL);
dispatch_async(fetchQ, ^{        
    NSArray *data = [MyAPI myData];   

    [document.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
        for (NSDictionary *info in data) {
            [MyEntity createOrUpdateGivenInfo:info andManagedObjectContext:self.myDatabase.managedObjectContext];
        }
    }];
});
dispatch_release(fetchQ);
```

This works fine: I get my updates and the table view is displaying everything correctly. Only problem is that the UI is unresponsive, presumably because I do the saving/updating on the main thread. So I looked into performing it on a background thread with this modification:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init WithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [backgroundContext setParentContext:self.myDatabase.managedObjectContext];

    [backgroundContext performBlock:^{      
      NSArray *data = [MyAPI myData];   

      for (NSDictionary *info in data) {
            [MyEntity createOrUpdateGivenInfo:info andManagedObjectContext:backgroundContext];
        }

      [backgroundContext save:nil];

      [document.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
        [document updateChangeCount:UIDocumentChangeDone];
      }];
    }];
```

However, while the UI is now responsive, I get loads of troubles with the table view: instead of updating an existing entry, the table displays an extra entry (a duplicate which shouldn't exist). I think it might be because the two contextes are not synced/merged, but from reading previous SO posts I was led to believe that I just needed to call save on the backgroundContext and then updateChangeCount on the main MOC. 
If I restart the app, everything works fine again - until I do another refresh.

Does anybody have any help to spare. I am literally starting to pull my hair out.

I'll give you beer if you can solve this mystery.

Comment: Your general idea for handling the background context is right.  Please post your code for createOrUpdateGivenInfo:andManagedObjectContext:  Oh yeah... also the setup for your NSFetchRequest and NSFetchedResultsController -- sounds like you may not be properly fetching or handling the merge.

Answer (score 2):

`UIManagedDocument` creates two contexts for you: A root context of `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` and a child context of `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`.

Hook up your `NSFetchedResultsController` to the `document.managedObjectContext` as you did, since that is the context for your main thread.

Reading/writing happens *automatically* on a background thread. `UIManagedDocument` takes care of that. You need not worry about it.

If you need to do some heavy lifting yourself, you create another managed object of `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`and make your `document.managedObjectContext` its parent.

I read your code and it looks like this is what you do and this should work. That's exactly how I do it in my apps. But I have seen several other people reporting duplicate entries with `NSFetchedResultsController` suspecting there's a framework bug.

If you are willing to share your project, I'd take a look.